# add elements in array list using for loop

Tags: android

I am trying to add elements into array lists.I have two list one list is giving me text name (A,B,C) and another list is giving the text value (10,20,30).Now i am getting these values into two array list Array List.

```
ArrayList<String> sh1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> sh2 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
int sum = 0;    
@Override     
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)      
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);      
ListView lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);     
for(int i = 0; i< MainActivity.er.size(); i++)    
{    
    sh1.add(MainActivity.er.get(i));        
        for(int j = 0; j< MyAdapter1.er1.size(); j++)    
        {
            //sh2.add(MyAdapter1.er1.get(j));    
            sum += Integer.parseInt(MyAdapter1.er1.get(j));     
        }    
        int summ = sum;     
        sh2.add(String.valueOf(summ));     
        System.out.println(""+summ);     
}     
MyAdapter2 mad2 = new MyAdapter2(MainActivity2.this, sh1,sh2);    
lv2.setAdapter(mad2);
```

i want my result is that text from list name and addition of text value from list two
like (a : 40),(b : 50) etc but i am getting (a : 40), (b : 80)

Answer (score 0):

make your `sum` to `zero` inside start of `for` loop

```
for(int i = 0; i< MainActivity.er.size(); i++)    
{    
    sum = 0;
    sh1.add(MainActivity.er.get(i));        
        for(int j = 0; j< MyAdapter1.er1.size(); j++)    
        {
            //sh2.add(MyAdapter1.er1.get(j));    
            sum += Integer.parseInt(MyAdapter1.er1.get(j));     
        }    
        int summ = sum;     
        sh2.add(String.valueOf(summ));     
        System.out.println(""+summ);     
}
```

Comment: hi rajan ks,i did it. but now result is  i pressed A & 10, B&20 i got result A:30,B:30